# Hibernate unique field creation

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am trying to add the following column in one of my application domain classes:

```
@Column(name="USER_NAME",length=20,nullable=false,unique=true)
private String userName;
```

Reason I am making this field unique is that I need to make sure that each of the application users username is unique.

But I get the following error whenever I try loading the application:

```
WARN : org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 1054, SQLState: 42S22
ERROR: org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - Unknown column 'employee0_.USER_NAME' in 'field list'
Nov 27, 2013 12:14:11 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
```

If I make unique = false, everything works just fine. So I am wondering why I get this error when I set unique = true? and how I can make sure that the username field is unique?

Thanks for your time

Comment: Have you verified there's a column by that name?

Comment: @mabi with unique=true, the column is not created on application load. with unique = false, the column is automatically created with no problem. The problem is not in column existence for sure as even if you created the column manually you will still get error

Comment: try adding `@Column(name="USER_NAME",length=20,nullable=false,unique=true)` in the getter method

Comment: Are you sure your hbm2ddl property is on create? : <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>

Answer (score 0):

if you say setting unique to false it works, and when it is set to true it fails, its like creating a unique index on a column on a sql table where the table already has NO unique values in that column, in that case, creating that unique index will fail.